# Vagrant + Puppet: execute script after deploy command not found

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I'm trying to execute a script after deploy with Vagrant + Puppet:

```
  include nginx
  $nginx_conf_path = "${files_path}/${fqdn}/etc/nginx/sites-available"
  nginx::site { 'test.example.com.conf' :
    source => "${nginx_conf_path}/test.example.com.conf",
  }

  exec { 'install-letsencrypt.sh test.example.com':
    require => [Nginx::Site['test.example.com.conf'], Class['profile::ssl']],
    command => 'install-letsencrypt.sh test.example.com',
    path    => '/home/vagrant/bin/'
  }
```

with `ssl.pp`:

```
class profile::ssl { 

  file { "/home/vagrant/bin" :
    ensure => "directory",
    owner  => "vagrant",
    group  => "vagrant",
  }

  file { "/home/vagrant/bin/install-letsencrypt.sh":
    ensure => "present",
    owner  => "vagrant",
    group  => "vagrant",
    mode => 700,
    source => "puppet:///modules/example/shared/install-letsencrypt.sh"
  }
}
```

And `install-letsencrypt.sh`:

```
if [ ! -d "/opt/letsencrypt" ]; then
  sudo git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt /opt/letsencrypt
fi
# ...etc
```

The `profile::ssl` works because `/home/vagrant/bin/install-letsencrypt.sh` is available, but when I try to `exec` it in puppet, I get:

```
==> test.example.com: Error: Deploying Let's encrypt for test.mojjo.fr
==> test.example.com: /home/vagrant/bin/install-letsencrypt.sh: line 11: sudo: command not found
==> test.example.com: /home/vagrant/bin/install-letsencrypt.sh: line 14: mkdir: command not found
==> test.example.com: /home/vagrant/bin/install-letsencrypt.sh: line 17: sudo: command not found
==> test.example.com: /home/vagrant/bin/install-letsencrypt.sh: line 23: sudo: command not found
==> test.example.com: /home/vagrant/bin/install-letsencrypt.sh: line 25: sudo: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried with absolute executable paths (`/usr/bin/sudo` instead of `sudo`) but it doesn't work either. If I `ssh test.example.com` and run it there, it also works, so the problème is not in the script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue to run some script so I did

```
  exec { 'run-script':
    command => "bash -c 'install-letsencrypt.sh test.example.com'",
    ....
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still got `/bin/bash: install-letsencrypt.sh: command not found`. I tried with `command => "/bin/bash -c 'install-letsencrypt.sh test.mojjo.fr'"` and with `command => "bash -c 'install-letsencrypt.sh test.mojjo.fr'", path => '/bin'`...

Comment: then put the full path of the script `/home/vagrant/bin/install-letsencrypt.sh` and make sure vagrant is running the script `user => 'vagrant'`

Comment: The `user => 'vagrant'` did the trick. Thanks. Not sure the `/bin/bash` is required then...

Comment: generally in my puppet exec I go with `'/usr/bin:/bin:...'`